# Pandas style won't change colors columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to highlight some values in some columns of a pandas dataframe. I have this code to do it: 
Sample dataframe:

```
    Name    ID Name_1  ID.1
0    cat  98.4    dog  98.4
1  cat.1  96.5  dog.1  96.5
2  cat.3  95.4  dog.3  95.4

def color_negative_red_1(value):
    if value <= 96.5:
        color='red'
    elif value == 97.5:
        color='blue'
    else:
        color='black'
    return ['background-color: red']
```

`df_1.style.applymap(color_negative_red_1,subset=['ID','ID.1'])`

Here is how it should look:

[image]

but there aren't any changes in my excell file...

Comment: why isnt 96.5 highlighted since your first condition says it should be red: `<= 96.5` means less than equal to 96.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. applymap works elementwise, you don't need to return list, it should be just the string.
2. You are always setting the color to red, you are not using the variable `color`

```py
def color_negative_red_1(value):
    if value <= 96.5:
        color='red'
    elif value == 97.5:
        color='blue'
    else:
        color='black' # a really bad idea, may be you should just set color = ''
    return 'background-color: {}'.format(color)
```

Comment: I don't know, I can't edit my excell in ordert to have this output

Comment: Good point , though you could just use `color='' ` under else  for no colors :)